# Creation of pipe-delimited hive table - duplicate ids

Tags: hive

I'm trying to create a pipe-delimited hive table using these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA (
id                      string,
col1                     double,
col2                     double,
col3                     double,
col4                     double,
col5                     double,
col6                     double,
col7                     double

)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");


INSERT INTO TABLE TABLEA
select a.id
       b.col1,
       b.col2,
       b.col3,
       b.col4,
       b.col5,
       b.col6,
       b.col7
FROM   customerTable as a  left join factTable as b  on a.id   = b.id;
```

I get duplicate records in the new table, tableA. I checked using

```
select count(distinct id) as cnt from tableA ;
```

Whereas if I create a normal hive table like this, I don't get any duplicate ids:

```
Create table if not exists tableA as 
select a.id
           b.col1,
           b.col2,
           b.col3,
           b.col4,
           b.col5,
           b.col6,
           b.col7
    FROM   customerTable as a  left join factTable as b  on a.id   = b.id;
```

The table created is in order of 80 Million rows but the difference in the number of records ( duplicate records) is only 58 records.

Not sure whats going on. I guess the problem is with how I'm creating the pipe-delimited hive table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove **tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");** property in your create table statement and run the insert statement again.

Comment: @Shu , the solution suggested by you actually worked. Thanks a ton. Please add it as an answer and I will recognize it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it worked.. :) added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove tblproperties **("skip.header.line.count"="1");** property in your create table statement and run the insert statement again.